# change file permission while transferring from local to server

Tags: linux, unix, command, scp

I have a file with 700 permission in my local. I need to move this file to abc directory in a server using scp command. Here, file permission should be 755 but I am getting file with 700 permission only. How can I set permission to 755 for all file moving to this directory as default.

Comment: try to use linux acl to remote directory.

Comment: I tried but its not working

Comment: I might be missing some steps. Could u please provide me step by step solution?

Answer (score 4):

You could use rsync for the transfer:

```
rsync --chmod=u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rx file.txt user@host:abc/
```

If you prefer to use scp, you could set permissions after the transfer:

```
scp file.txt user@host:abc/
ssh user@host 'chmod 755 abc/file.txt'
```